# Using an advice to set default parameters in a interactive function

Tags: advice, gpg, erc, pgp, authinfo

I'm not sure if this is possible or if there's a workaround for it, but I want `M-x erc` to set the password *after* I try to call it, but *before* I input the actual parameters.

What I originally had in my init.el was

```
(let ((erc-plist (car (auth-source-search :host "irc.freenode.net"))))
  (setq erc-server "irc.freenode.net")
  (setq erc-nick (plist-get erc-plist :user))
  (setq erc-password (funcall (plist-get erc-plist :secret))))
```

But this runs on startup, which is less than ideal because I run Emacs as a systemd user unit, and it needs to decrypt `authinfo.gpg`

So I tried to create an advice like the following:

```
(defadvice erc (:before (&key (server (erc-compute-server))
                              (port   (erc-compute-port))
                              (nick   (erc-compute-nick))
                              password
                              (full-name (erc-compute-full-name))))
  "Set up nick and password before running ERC."
  (let ((erc-plist (car (auth-source-search :host "irc.freenode.net"))))
    (setq erc-server "irc.freenode.net")
    (setq erc-nick (plist-get erc-plist :user))
    (setq erc-password (funcall (plist-get erc-plist :secret)))))
```

But the advice will only run after I input the parameters from ERC, so it's already too late.

I also use helm, so if it's possible to add some hook for helm to run a function right after I select erc from the menu, it would solve my problem.

Comment: The question is unclear. Please specify exactly what you are trying to do, preferably showing what (code) you already tried.

Comment: @Drew ok, edited with some more details.

Comment: `erc` is an autoload function. If you only need to get authentication once you can call your password setup with `eval-after-load` for package `erc.el`. Is there any reason that forces you to use `defadvice` instead of `advice-add`? If you really need to call the password setup at each interactive call of `erc` you must add an interactive-form to your advice that overrides the original interactive form. In the new interactive form you first do the password setup and afterwards do the original stuff, i.e., `(interactive (progn (...passowrd-setup...) (erc-select-read-args)))`.

Comment: It's still not clear (to me), what the *question* is. I don't see a question.

Comment: @Tobias no, I don't need to use `defadvice`, it was just one of the things I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own command to set all variables before starting ERC:

```
(defun my/erc-freenode ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((erc-plist (car (auth-source-search :host "irc.freenode.net")))
        (erc-prompt-for-password nil))
    (setq erc-server "irc.freenode.net")
    (setq erc-nick (plist-get erc-plist :user))
    (setq erc-password (funcall (plist-get erc-plist :secret)))
    (erc)))
```

Then, you have to type `M-x my/erc-freenode` to start ERC on Freenode.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that does it.